# Azure ComputerVision OCR and PDF format

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I found several older questions on if and how to do OCR by using Cognitive Services. On [Cognitive services](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51704.cognitive-services-optical-character-recognition-ocr-from-an-image-using-computer-vision-api-and-c.aspx) I can find a step-by-step description which tells me that and how OCR from PDF can be done. 
When I do it like the example memntioned at the bottom of the page, I still get that unsuppertdMediaType result

> {
>       "code": "UnsupportedMediaType",
>       "requestId": "c427e1c7-3f99-4a74-a36f-1620e68e3b64",
>       "message": "Supported media types: application/octet-stream, multipart/form-data or application/json" }

When I change the PDF to an image everything is fine. 
I currently follow [cognitive-services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-print-text)
but while the request seems to be fine, the document type still is unsupported. 
I call:

https://.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v2.0/ocr?language=de&detectOrientation=true&Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key=&Content-Type=application/octet-stream

and the file is contained in the body, of course.

I don't post the C# or PowerShell, as the problem indeed seems to be with my request from the URL mentioned above.

Can someone please help me understand how to get a valid request to get text from a PDF with Azure ComputerVision?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because OCR doesn't support PDF as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text#ocr-optical-character-recognition-api)

> The OCR API works on images that meet the following requirements:
>
> - The image must be presented in JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP format.
> - The size of the input image must be between 50 x 50 and 4200 x 4200    pixels.
> - The text in the image can be rotated by any multiple of 90 degrees    plus a small angle of up to 40 degrees.

That being said, you can use the new Read API as it supports PDF as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text#read-api)

> The Read API works with images that meet the following requirements:
>
> - The image must be presented in JPEG, PNG, BMP, PDF, or TIFF format.
> - The dimensions of the image must be between 50 x 50 and 10000 x 10000    pixels. PDF pages must be 17 x 17 inches or smaller.
> - The file size of the image must be less than 20 megabytes (MB).

It is guaranteed to work if you follow the requirements and use the right endpoint!